# Simple cpp error? error LNK2005: "int AAA" (?AAA@@3HA) already defined in ConsoleApplication1.obj

Tags: c++

ConsoleApplication1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Test.h"
#include "Head1.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Test.h

```
#pragma once
int AAA = 1;
```

Head1.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Test.h"
```

Head2.h

```
#pragma once

class Head2C
{

public:
    void Print();
};
```

Head2.cpp

```
#include "Head2.h"
#include "Head1.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Head2C::Print()
{
    cout << "Head2::Print() " << endl;
}
```

Why #pragma once can't work for this sample code?

**The linker error : error LNK2005: "int AAA" (?AAA@@3HA) already defined in ConsoleApplication1.obj**

Comment: `Test1.h` or `Test.h`. Please [edit] and clarify.

Answer (score 5):

Every non-constant variable should be defined only once in the entire program. `#pragma once` only ensures that it is defined once for each translation unit (cpp file). With two translation units, you are defining the variable twice in the entire program.

Make `AAA` constant or move the definition into a cpp file.

Comment: Since C++17, it could also be made `inline`.